# Retrofit LED can light

Tags: lighting, led

In the past, I've replaced old incandescent can lights with LEDs and it has been a breeze.

For the latest can light I'm replacing though, the attachment is different and I can't find an LED retrofit that would seem to work.

This is the inside of the current can and the trim that attaches using the slots at the top:

[image]
[image]

Here is a typical retrofit LED:

[image]

The can doesn't have the holes on the side for the prongs of the retrofit LED.  Instead there are some clips right next to the light socket.  There are also the vertical slots closer to the bottom of the can but I don't know what they are for.

Is there a way to attach this LED to this can?  Another LED that would work?  Or am I out of luck?

Comment: How was the former trim held in? The "slots & holes" arrangement is usually for coiled springs.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, by the two clips next to the light socket near the top of the can.

Comment: Does the existing fixture have a diffuser, or just a trim ring?

Comment: I see two slots in that photo.

Comment: @Mattman944, updated question with more details.

Comment: @Jasen, those slots won't work.  The prongs of the LED are a torsion spring so the holes for it need to be closer together for it to work.

Comment: I can't tell if it has a diffuser. If it does, a regular LED bulb worked for me. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/190410/bathroom-ceiling-light-led-retrofit

Comment: @Mattman944, ah, I see what you are getting at.  There is not a diffuser.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution.  You can buy [these on Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MUCX5H4):

The are called "**Retrofit Recessed Downlight Housing C Clips** with Self Tapping Screws for Down Light Can"

You screw them onto the wall of the can, and then you have slots to hold the torsion spring of the LED.

They seem to be available only on Amazon (*not even the big box stores*) so not an easy thing to find.

[image]